# Creating a reusable WINDOW control

Tags: c#, wpf, window

Okay, this seems to be very hard, or I am missing something obvious. 
I want to create reusable WINDOW which will be used all over the products. It means that the control is inside WPF.Controls assembly. Themes/Generic.xaml is not a solution, I need to provide my own code for the window, such as custom message hook, etc.

Here is my code in WPF.Controls.dll:

```
public class CustomWindow : Window
{
    static CustomWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
 typeof(CustomWindow),
 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow)));
    }
```

Now, in another assembly, I create XAML file and try to use this:

```
<controls:CustomWindow x:Class="Views.MainWindow"
                               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                               xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WPF.Controls;assembly=WPF.Controls"
                               WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<TextBlock Text="TESTING" />
</controls:CustomWindow>
```

What I see: big black screen, nothing else, nothing less(big black rectangle - no caption bar). Can anyone shed some light over this? With a bit of googling, I found that somebody else had same problem, so I guess it's not specific to me.

Disabling hardware rendering doesn't help.

Comment: [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#styling_a_window) Project allows you to have a reusable Window, this is an open-source project, so you can look how these guys did it.

Comment: Which version of .NET?  Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2012. I suspect it might be reproducable in other versions too.

Comment: I'm really curious about the solution to this. Please keep us informed if you can resolve this problem. I'm able to reproduce it, but I didn't think it'd be so tricky to find a fix. I've exhausted all my ideas. :)

Comment: I had the same problem with my app. Something smelly was in  `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` inside App.xaml. Can you post your App.xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the static constructor from you CustomWindow-class. The purpose of setting the DefaultStyleKey is to help WPF find your defaulttemplate that should be defined in Themes/Generic.xaml. But since you don't want to do that then you need to remove it.

I tested your code by adding the CustomWindow class to a class library project (had to import quite a few dependencies) and then used it in a WPF project. With your constructor in place all of the content of the window was black, and once I removed it everything worked perfectly.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good resource on making your own controls

> // Chris Eelmaa: This is correct, also, I'd like to add that it's also
>   possible to add Themes/Generic.xaml to your dll, and then you need to
>   add the assembly `ThemeInfo` attribute to your DLL (AssemblyInfo.cs),
>   in order for it to work:

```
// http://blogs.magnatis.com/tim/dude-wheres-my-default-style
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific 
    // resource dictionaries are located 
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the
    // generic resource dictionary is located 
)]
```

Comment: I will try this suggestion in few days, but as far I remember, I tried tons of different combinations, including without/with etc.